# MySQL: I cannot execute an script

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-error-1064

I made a database with MySQL Workbench on windows 7 and run it on local. Everything runs well but now, i want to install my database inside my own server, ubuntu, and when i run the script an error is showed.

.\myDatabase.sql

ERROR.
Unknown command '\b'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; chech the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user ner '.\myDatabase.sql' at line 1

I have looked for \b and i think that is the syntax to indicate the end of the word. Although i cannot to solve this problem.

Thankyou!

---

In my first line i have:
    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;

Comment: Post the code that is causing the error. `\b` is a regexp word boundary in some implementations, but I think it is a backspace literal in MySQL.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

My mysql client has no '\b' command. It does accept '.' as an alias for [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) (which appears to be what you're trying to achieve here).